How to avoid sorting when query?


A food name will be shown on col 'First meal' when a checkbox is checked, but it is auto sort if multiple checkbox are checked.
I use =QUERY(A3:B5,"select A where B=TRUE label A 'First meal'").
I want a food name ordered by order of checkbox selection.
For example 

This cannot be done with a formula unless you had a timestamp recorded in another column.  You could then sort by the timestamp.  (A timestamp in another column could be added via Apps Script and you could then hide the column if necessary.)
